# Roxygen2: How do document a function returned in a function closure?

Tags: r, closures, documentation, roxygen2

My package has a function closure that takes a function as parameter and returns another function, that does several operations according to the function passed. Here's an example:

```
#' @param operation A function to be used.
#' @return A function that has parameters 'a' and 'b' and I can't document.

create_fun <- function(operation){
  fn <- function(a,b){
    operation(a,b)*8
  }
  return(fn)
}

f1 <- create_fun(max)
f2 <- create_fun(min)
f1(1,2)
# 16
f2(1,2)
# 8
```

While `roxygen2` allows a very simple documentation of `create_fun`, I can't figure out how to use roxygen to tell the user how to use the function created (i.e. what are its arguments `a` and `b`, what it returns, etc.)

Is there any feature on `roxygen2` or any other option that helps me document the returned function?

Comment: I'm guessing you've already decided this isn't what you want to do, for some reason, but I would just describe the signature and use of the returned function in detail in the `@return` section.

Comment: That is how I'm using it right now, but I wonder if there was an ellegant way of having something like 'subsections' of `@return` with `@param` and `@return`. I guess even `@details` could be used. Just can't figure out what is the standard as closures aren't that common in packages.

Comment: See [this github post](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/453). Looks like it is not possible. Hadley recommends using the @return.

Comment: Actually you can document inner functions, just only outside of its body. You can place any arbitrary document snippets outside below the function and name them as you like. Just place random Robject under snippet also e.g. 42 or "fruit-box"

```#' Sum lists
#' @name arr_sum
#' @description
#' Sum all the lists in the array.
#' @keywords ExprArr
#' @format my_inner_function
#' @return Expr
#' @aliases arr_sum arr.sum
#' @examples
#' df = pl$DataFrame(values = pl$Series(list(1L,2:3)))
#' df$select(pl$col("values")$arr$sum())
42 # any Robject here triggers rendering
```

Comment: example from here, for smaller examples the @return-field is probably fine also
https://github.com/pola-rs/r-polars/blob/50b442a66dd8c647b44cec0873c14b3ae74a8e35/R/expr__list.R#L10